# could not launch the product because the specified workspace cannot be created eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have delete the .lock file but Still it's not working. I have delete whole .metadata file but still it's not opening the workspace. I have also create a new directory of workspace but same error. Give me solution of this error

Comment: Hi @Faisal, I believe your question is incomplete(not clear much). Kindly provide more information. And follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: my Question is when I am using spring tool suit I want to go to my previous workspace. I good error of " could not launch the product because the specified workspace cannot be created eclipse " So then I have delete the .lock file from workspace but still I can't open the workspace. and same error is displaying

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this

-->>Goto .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi and remove workbench.xmi file from that workspace to solve this issue:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.  now workspace opened but the when I import the projects its give error. "The system cannot find the path specified". give me solution for this. I don't know whats happened to the IDE.

Comment: Are you using Maven based Structure?